# Need to calculate count of ticket for each customer on a selected date alone with daily sales on quantity and total

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to calculate the number of ticket for selected time period, and this number of ticket should be per customer.
Below is the table , in which I have line level data.

```
Invoice No |  Customer  | date       | Amount
1                 C1     01/01/2020      500
2                 C2     01/01/2020      600
3                 C3     02/01/2020      200
4                 C2     02/01/2020      200
5                 C1     03/01/2020      400
6                 C1     04/01/2020      300
```

My output should be like below

```
Customer Name | Date        | InvoiceNo | Total invoice | Total Amount 
C1              01/01/2020    1           3                      900
C1              03/01/2020    5           3                      900
C1              04/01/2020    6           3                      900
C2              01/01/2020    2           2                      800
C2              02/01/2020    4           2                      800
C3              02/01/2020    3           1                      200
```

I can get the expected output from my below sql query

```
select A.Customer, B.docN, B.amount AS DocumentTotal,  
A.date AS Date FROM
(select  InvoiceNo,Customer,date from Table1
Where date>=’20200201 00 :00 :00’ and date <=’20200201 00:00:00’
) A
join 
(select Customer,sum(amount) as Amount,count(InvoiceNo) as docN from Table1
where date>=’20200201 00 :00 :00’ and date <=’20200201 00:00:00’
group by Customer) B
on A.Customer =B.Customer
```

And the problem is I will select **FROM DATE** and **TO DATE** in the filter.And my filter is inside **A** ,So the Total Invoice value in **B** is not respecting the selected date. Please advice me how to use one filter for date and that should be for both A and B

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Presumably the expected output you have posted doesn't come from the sample data you have posted?

Comment: Yes... My table and data are different... I just created a dummy data to explain

Comment: You are joining table on the basis of Customer that is wrong since same customer will be repeated for multiple invoices, so it will be cross join and amount will go wrong. Just join both tables  on Invoice_no and do group by on customer, you will get desired output

Answer (score 1):

Try below and let us know, only thing here is you wont get invoice_numbers

```
    select  Customer,count(A.InvoiceNo) as Total_Invoice,date,sum(B.amount) as Total_Amount  from Table1  A
    join Table2 B
    on A.InvoiceNo =B.InvoiceNo 
    Where A.date>=’20200201 00 :00 :00’ and A.date <=’20200201 00:00:00’
    group by A.Customer
```

Comment: If you really need invoice_numbers also you can do a self join or use aggregate function like STRING_AGG(Invoice_Number) to get it.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to just want window functions:

```
select customer_name, date, invoice_number,
       count(*) over (partition by customer_name) as num_invoices,
       sum(amount) over (partition by customer_name) as total_amount
from t
order by num_invoices desc,
         customer_name,
         date;
```

If you add a `where` clause, it will apply to all columns.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below query. This will give the total invoice and amount with date filtration.

```
select A.customer,A.date,invoice_no,B.Total_Invoice,B.Total_Amount from test A join
(select customer,date,count(invoice_no) over (partition by customer) as Total_Invoice,
SUM(amount) over (partition by customer) as Total_Amount from test
where date>='20200101 00 :00 :00' and date <='20200301 00:00:00'
)B 
on A.date=B.date and A.customer=B.customer
order by customer;
```

Output:

```
C1  2020-01-01  1   2   900
C1  2020-03-01  5   2   900
C2  2020-01-01  2   2   800
C2  2020-02-01  4   2   800
C3  2020-02-01  3   1   200
```

And if you want total invoice(without date filtration) and total amount (with date filtration) then you can use the following query.

```
select distinct A.customer,A.date,invoice_no,C.Total_Invoice,B.Total_Amount from test A join
(select customer,date,count(invoice_no) over (partition by customer) as Total_Invoice,
SUM(amount) over (partition by customer) as Total_Amount from test
where date>='20200101 00 :00 :00' and date <='20200301 00:00:00'
)B 
on A.date=B.date and A.customer=B.customer
join 
(select customer,COUNT(invoice_no) over (partition by customer) as Total_Invoice from test)C
on A.customer=C.customer
order by customer;
```

Output:

```
C1  2020-01-01  1   3   900
C1  2020-03-01  5   3   900
C2  2020-01-01  2   2   800
C2  2020-02-01  4   2   800
C3  2020-02-01  3   1   200
```